# Is there a way to use CompatRouter from react-router-dom-v5-compat with data APIs/createBrowserRouter?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I'm trying to use the new useMatches hook from the v5-compat [lib](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-matches). According to the migration [guide](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/discussions/8753), the implementation should be as simple as this:

```
        import {
          CompatRouter,
        } from "react-router-dom-v5-compat";
        
        // other stuff

        <BrowserRouter>
          <CompatRouter> // nest inside v5 router
            <Switch>
              <Route path={BASE_PATH}>
                <App />
              </Route>
              <Route>
                <Redirect to={BASE_PATH} />
              </Route>
            </Switch>
          </CompatRouter>
        </BrowserRouter>
```

However, if you then try to use useMatches, you get the following error:

`useMatches must be used within a data router.`

I would use createBrowserRouter (or similar data API), but this is a huge application so I want to incrementally upgrade my routes. By using something liek createBrowserRouter, I'd have to replace the entire BrowserRouter -- which is too big of a change.

Is there a way to incrementally change with CompatRouter **and** make use of the new useMatches, without having to do a huge rewrite all at once?

Comment: No, if you want to use the `useMatches` hook you'll need to use a Data Router.